# Connecting a Java Servlet to a Browser

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I've tried this question before with little success but that's probably my fault so I'll be as specific as possible!

Part A)
I have a compiled java class which returns a hello world string. The source code for this file is below. After configuring the web.xml setting I am able to get good results from a browser pointing at localhost. This is working exactly as planned.

Part B)
I have an HTML landing page with a single link in it which, when pressed will read a local text file and replace content within it. This is also working exactly as planned.

Part A means I am able to have a client call a server-side java class file and get outputs. Part B means I am able to replace one part of a webpage after a button has been pressed.

My question, from this point is quite straight forward. I would like to merge the two concepts so that when the link from part B is pressed the text updated will reflect the 'hello world' result set from Part A.

Thanks in advance.

Part A Code:

```
package mypkg;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      try {
         out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         out.println("<html><head>");
         out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
         out.println("<title>Hello, World</title></head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");  
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  
      }
   }
}
```

Part B Code

```
<p id="mySentence">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getNewContent();">Click here to update the page</a>.
When you click the link, this content will be replaced.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var http = createRequestObject();
function createRequestObject() {
    var objAjax;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        objAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return objAjax;
}

function getNewContent(){
http.open('get','newcontent.txt');
http.onreadystatechange = updateNewContent;
http.send(null);
return false;
}

function updateNewContent(){
if(http.readyState == 4){
document.getElementById('mySentence').innerHTML = http.responseText;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Read about implementing servlets.  try here: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Comment: You can learn the basics of Servlets here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info